# Access VBA getting DateDiff results to work with Update SQL statement

Tags: ms-access, vba, datediff

I'm using Access 2007 by itself with no connections to SQLserver or anything for this process.

I want to take the result of a few `DateDiff` functions and use an Update SQL statement to put them into fields on a table.  My table's fields are number fields, and I am under the impression that `DateDiff` returns a number.

I try this, but I get a `data type mismatch` error on the first `DateDiff` (Pause1).  I tried taking the quotes off of the fields but then I get a different error (`can't find the field '|' referred to in your expression`).

Here is my code.  It really starts at the comment `TIME REPORTING CODE HERE`:

```
Private Sub StopNextButton_Click()
'
GetID = Forms!frm_MainMenu!AssocIDBox
CurRecord = Forms!frm_EC_L1_L2![L#].Value
'
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Data SET tbl_Data.[tsEndAll] = Now WHERE tbl_Data.[L#] = " & CurRecord & " AND (tbl_Data.[ECName] Like 'L1*' OR tbl_Data.[ECName] Like 'L2*') "
'
'TIME REPORTING CODE HERE'
'
Pause1 = DateDiff("s", "[tsPause1]", "[tsResume1]")
Pause2 = DateDiff("s", "[tsPause2]", "[tsResume2]")
ECTime = (DateDiff("s", "[tsECStart]", "[tsUpdated]") - (Pause1 + Pause2))
LTime = DateDiff("s", "[tsStartAll]", "[tsEndAll]")
'
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Data SET [ECTime] = " & ECTime & ", [LoanTime] = " & LTime & " WHERE tbl_Data.[L#] = " & CurRecord & " AND (tbl_Data.[ECName] Like 'L1*' OR tbl_Data.[ECName] Like 'L2*') "
'
'END OF TIME REPORTING CODE'
'
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
'
ETC.
```

Comment: What do you think/intend to refer to when you say tsPause1 ortsResume1?  Fields on a table, controls on a form, or possibly something else?

Comment: fields in the table that have Datetime values in them.  Sorry thanks for asking.

Comment: No problem, just looking for clarification.  Based off what I think you are trying to do I have posted what I believe is the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of your comment I assume that those fields are on the record your form is currently 'viewing'.  If so you can just refer to them as Me.tsPause1 without [] or quotes.  Pretty sure you can also do just tsPause1 but I find Me.tsPause1 makes it more obvious what you are doing.

However I think you are updating the field you are currently viewing and then immediately trying to access those updated fields.  I am fairly certain you will need to a Me.Refresh before those fields' new values are accessible.  Hopefully someone with more specific experience will correct me if I am wrong. I think something like this should work for you:

```vb
Me.Refresh
Pause1 = DateDiff("s", Me.tsPause1, Me.tsResume1)
Pause2 = DateDiff("s", Me.tsPause2, Me.tsResume2)
ECTime = (DateDiff("s", Me.tsECStart, Me.tsUpdated) - (Pause1 + Pause2))
LTime = DateDiff("s", Me.tsStartAll, Me.tsEndAll)
```

Comment: i would like it to do this for a number of records that are all related by the same `[L#]` value.  So they won't be on the form.  I think I could put this elsewhere and get it to work for each record, so this is a big help, but how would I do this if all of the fields I need for my `DateDiff` are not on the form?  Kind of like a loop but only through the records that pertain to the `[L#]` value.  Thanks!

Comment: To do this you will need to become familiar with recordsets.  I would recommend reading through this link, Allen Browne's website is amazing for all things access.  http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html

Comment: Allen Browne is my spirit animal.  I haven't fully grasped recordsets but I will keep trying.  Thanks!